# Only page admins are able to open FB posts from our WP website as Instant Articles, everyone else sees them as links that redirect to our website

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress-plugin-creation, facebook-instant-articles

As stated above, I have been trying to configure instant articles for a news website. i have set up the FB instant articles for wp plugin to access the page through a FB app that I linked to the plugin using the app ID, secret, and Page access token (made using this guide ). The plugin seems to be working fine and posts made on the website are automatically converted to Instant Articles when their links are posted on FB. However only our page admins seem able to open these posts on facebook as instant articles; for all other audience the links open normally, directly to our website. Please help on how I can fix this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sounds like your app is probably still in dev mode, and you need to take it into live mode. (Or find the appropriate mode, if it is a business app.) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-modes